# VSCode different permissions when opened with CLI versus shortcut (macOS Catalina)

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I am using the OmniSharp/Microsoft C# extension with VSCode. When I open my project using the `code .` command inside my project folder, the extension is able to find the dotnet SDKs just fine and everything is good.

When I open VSCode using the shortcut icon, I get this error output from OmniSharp:

```
Starting OmniSharp server at 1/13/2020, 8:00:34 PM
    Target: /Users/finley/dev/courses/dotnet/DatingApp

OmniSharp server started.
    Path: /Users/finley/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.9/.omnisharp/1.34.9/run
    PID: 16347

[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Starting OmniSharp on MacOS 10.15.2 (x64)
[info]: OmniSharp.Services.DotNetCliService
        DotNetPath set to dotnet
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Located 1 MSBuild instance(s)
            1: StandAlone 16.3 - "/Users/finley/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.9/.omnisharp/1.34.9/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        MSBUILD_EXE_PATH environment variable set to '/Users/finley/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.9/.omnisharp/1.34.9/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.dll'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.Discovery.MSBuildLocator
        Registered MSBuild instance: StandAlone 16.3 - "/Users/finley/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.9/.omnisharp/1.34.9/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin"
            CscToolExe = csc.exe
            MSBuildToolsPath = /Users/finley/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.9/.omnisharp/1.34.9/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin
            CscToolPath = /Users/finley/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.9/.omnisharp/1.34.9/omnisharp/.msbuild/Current/Bin/Roslyn
            BypassFrameworkInstallChecks = true
            MSBuildExtensionsPath = /Users/finley/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.csharp-1.21.9/.omnisharp/1.34.9/omnisharp/.msbuild
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Detecting Cake files in '/Users/finley/dev/courses/dotnet/DatingApp'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Cake.CakeProjectSystem
        Could not find any Cake files
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectSystem
        No solution files found in '/Users/finley/dev/courses/dotnet/DatingApp'
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Queue project update for '/Users/finley/dev/courses/dotnet/DatingApp/DatingApp.API/DatingApp.API.csproj'
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Detecting CSX files in '/Users/finley/dev/courses/dotnet/DatingApp'.
[info]: OmniSharp.Script.ScriptProjectSystem
        Could not find any CSX files
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.CSharpFormattingWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 0
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.RenameWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 100
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Invoking Workspace Options Provider: OmniSharp.Roslyn.CSharp.Services.EditorConfigWorkspaceOptionsProvider, Order: 200
[info]: OmniSharp.WorkspaceInitializer
        Configuration finished.
[info]: OmniSharp.Stdio.Host
        Omnisharp server running using Stdio at location '/Users/finley/dev/courses/dotnet/DatingApp' on host 16330.
[info]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Loading project: /Users/finley/dev/courses/dotnet/DatingApp/DatingApp.API/DatingApp.API.csproj
  It was not possible to find any installed .NET Core SDKs
  Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
      https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Failed to load project file '/Users/finley/dev/courses/dotnet/DatingApp/DatingApp.API/DatingApp.API.csproj'.
/Users/finley/dev/courses/dotnet/DatingApp/DatingApp.API/DatingApp.API.csproj(1,1)
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found.  /Users/finley/dev/courses/dotnet/DatingApp/DatingApp.API/DatingApp.API.csproj
  at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject (System.String errorSubCategoryResourceName, Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String resourceName, System.Object[] args) [0x00040] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.VerifyThrowInvalidProject[T1] (System.Boolean condition, System.String errorSubCategoryResourceName, Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String resourceName, T1 arg0) [0x00003] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject[T1] (Microsoft.Build.Shared.IElementLocation elementLocation, System.String resourceName, T1 arg0) [0x00000] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpressionConditioned (System.String directoryOfImportingFile, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement]& projects, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResult& sdkResult, System.Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsError) [0x00254] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].ExpandAndLoadImports (System.String directoryOfImportingFile, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResult& sdkResult) [0x00027] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].EvaluateImportElement (System.String directoryOfImportingFile, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectImportElement importElement) [0x0000d] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].PerformDepthFirstPass (Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport) [0x000e6] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].Evaluate (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingService, Microsoft.Build.Framework.BuildEventContext buildEventContext) [0x0011c] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4[P,I,M,D].Evaluate (Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IEvaluatorData`4[P,I,M,D] data, Microsoft.Build.Construction.ProjectRootElement root, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, System.Int32 maxNodeCount, Microsoft.Build.Collections.PropertyDictionary`1[T] environmentProperties, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingService, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IItemFactory`2[S,T] itemFactory, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.IToolsetProvider toolsetProvider, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectRootElementCacheBase projectRootElementCache, Microsoft.Build.Framework.BuildEventContext buildEventContext, Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.ISdkResolverService sdkResolverService, System.Int32 submissionId, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext, System.Boolean interactive) [0x0002f] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Reevaluate (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x0005e] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00035] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.ILoggingService loggingServiceForEvaluation, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00000] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.ReevaluateIfNecessary (Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00007] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Initialize (System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00126] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Context.EvaluationContext evaluationContext) [0x00093] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, System.String subToolsetVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings) [0x00000] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectLoadSettings loadSettings) [0x00000] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project..ctor (System.String projectFile, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion, Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection projectCollection) [0x00000] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject (System.String fileName, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] globalProperties, System.String toolsVersion) [0x000f7] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection.LoadProject (System.String fileName, System.String toolsVersion) [0x00000] in <10b73e4bf233421cae439ef765e97ef0>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.EvaluateProjectFileCore (System.String filePath) [0x0003f] in <21e2225264e848eb88f797c7e4a5cc78>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader.BuildProject (System.String filePath) [0x0000d] in <21e2225264e848eb88f797c7e4a5cc78>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo.Load (System.String filePath, OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectIdInfo projectIdInfo, OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectLoader loader) [0x00015] in <21e2225264e848eb88f797c7e4a5cc78>:0 
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager+<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<LoadProject>b__0 () [0x00000] in <21e2225264e848eb88f797c7e4a5cc78>:0 
  at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.Func`1[System.ValueTuple`3[OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectFile.ProjectFileInfo,System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1[OmniSharp.MSBuild.Logging.MSBuildDiagnostic],OmniSharp.MSBuild.Notification.ProjectLoadedEventArgs]].invoke_TResult()
  at OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager.LoadOrReloadProject (System.String projectFilePath, System.Func`1[TResult] loader) [0x0001b] in <21e2225264e848eb88f797c7e4a5cc78>:0 

[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: /Users/finley/dev/courses/dotnet/DatingApp/DatingApp.API/DatingApp.API.csproj
```

As you can see, it is unable to find my dotnet SDKs, indicating that VSCode was unable to run the `dotnet --info` command on behalf of the C# extension.

I'm sure the solution to this should be simple, but I am unable to figure it out! Any help would be greatly appreciated! I will provide any other debugging information necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appeared to be solved by simply restarting my computer. If you are running into this same issue, I would suggest giving it a try!